# memory game made on visual basic?

Tags: .net

i've been trying to run this visual basic .net code and it runs but has a problem when making a picturebox invisible, the entire thing is supposed to be a memory game similar to that old one about cards from purble place. During the validation of the second picturebox it doesnt show the image that is behind it.

Here it is my code:

Imports System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Public img1 As Integer
Public img2 As Integer
Public card1 As PictureBox
Public card2 As PictureBox

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Card_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim card As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)

    If img1 = 0 And img2 = 0 Then
        ' Primera tarjeta seleccionada
        img1 = card.Tag
        card1 = card
        card1.Visible = False
        Label1.Text = ToString(img1)



    ElseIf img1 <> 0 And img2 = 0 Then
        ' Segunda tarjeta seleccionada
        img2 = card.Tag
        card2 = card
        card2.Visible = False

        Label1.Text = ToString(img2)
        If img1 = img2 Then
            card1.Visible = False
            card2.Visible = False
            img1 = 0
            img2 = 0
        Else
            card1.Visible = True
            card2.Visible = True
            img1 = 0
            img2 = 0
        End If

    End If
End Sub




Private Sub caja1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles caja1.Click
    Card_Click(caja1, e)

End Sub

Private Sub caja2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles caja2.Click
    Card_Click(caja2, e)
End Sub

Private Sub caja3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles caja3.Click
    Card_Click(caja3, e)
End Sub
```

End Class